# Cannot access HashMap inside view template of Play-1.2

Tags: java, groovy, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to get the value of a template rendered in a string.

Here's my controller code:

```
Template template = TemplateLoader.load("app/views/Reports/dummy.html");    
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("dummy key", "dummy value");
play.Logger.debug("rendered template - " + template.render(map));
```

And below is how i'm trying to access the map in my view

```
#{list items:map.keySet(), as:'key'}
   //some manipulation      
#{/list}
```

But when the action is invoked the error below is shown:

> Execution error occurred in template /app/views/Reports/dummy.html.
>   Exception raised was NullPointerException : Cannot invoke method
>   keySet() on null object.

I can't figure out what went wrong. I'm using 1.2.5.3 of play framework and groovy template engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the map itself you give to the template engine but the keys within:

```
map.put("key", "value");
```

In the template you can then access it via

```
${key}
```